# How to do shortcuts using selenium and python for tor browser?

Tags: python, selenium, shortcut, tor, tor-browser-bundle

I am trying to create a new identity (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) in the tor browser controlled by python and selenium. Unfortunately, sendkeys does not work and I would prefer to use a headless browser and not use pyautogui. Any tips, advice, or other tips for the new identity trick would be much appreciated!

P.S. I think [@user14892837](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637984/keyboard-shortcuts-do-not-work-in-selenium-firefox-python) was trying to do this last year? Any update? Thanks

Comment: Who is @user14892837? What did they do last year? Your code trials?

Comment: no clue who they are but they're the only person who had the same problem (read about it in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637984/keyboard-shortcuts-do-not-work-in-selenium-firefox-python)

Comment: as I know selenium can control only part which renders page - it can't control menu and other elements (they removed this functionality) - so `command, shift, U` may not work. It may need to use `PyAutoGUI` or similar tools which can send key to system and it may send it to active window - but this need to display browser and make it focused (top window)

Comment: I didn't actually get your problem, are you trying to use sendkeys and it's not working? so share your code please. and it doesn't make sense to use pyautogui as you said.